# How to delay further UI requests until current promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

In a web page where I am have a input that is being calculated by a server promise.

Now, if the user star typing before the result is completed, all of his text will be replaced by the promise result.

I need to hold, or block, the key events, like a synchronous method, so, even if the user star typing before the promise results, the keys events would be performed after the promise resolves.

Current bad behaviour:

1. Promise is called, when it return it will change the content of the input to "hello";
2. User already know this, and start typing " wo"
3. The promise resolves changing the input from " wo" to "hello"
4. User keeps typing "rld"...
5. Final result of the input: "hellorld";

Desired good behaviour:

1. Promise is called, when it return it will change the content of the input to "hello";
2. User already know this, and start typing " wo", but input won't change
3. The promise resolves changing the input from "" to "hello"
4. The previous key events are processed, changing the input from "hello" to "hello wo"
5. User keeps typing "rld"...
6. Final result of the input: "hello world";

Is this somehow possible with promises, or I am need to keep using sync contexts to keep this behavior?

Comment: Suspending the events will only block the (perceived) user interaction. What you want to do is prepend the resolved value of promise to the value of input, like `promise.then((value) => input.value = value + input.value)`

Comment: _"User already know this, and start typing ' wo', but input won't change"_ - it is better to just disable the input until server responds. Allowing user to enter input but not showing its result immediately is also bad.

Comment: @UmbQbify: Yes, but there is no guarantee that the user only types regular keys. The user can type: "Shift + home + Del" for instance...

Comment: @Yousaf From an usability stand point of view, I disagree. Because if the field is disabled, the keys fired would be in other place... Or, forcing the user to keep waiting isn't a good practice either... If can't find an async solution, would be better work with the sync one...

Comment: I would just disable the field until the server responds and the field is populated. Also show a small loading spinner next to the input, or inside it, to indicate that some processing it going on in the background related to the input. This IMHO is far better than what your want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. You can concatenate strings for the input instead of replacing it.

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value += response.value;
```

2. You can capture all input events into local variable and update input only after server response.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the user only types regular keys. The user can type: "Shift + home" + Del for instance...

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this by storing the key events values in some state and apply the state after the promise resolves. Here is a trivial example (should be improved with cases event is not just a letter, like delete backward, key enter, etc...).

```js
const state = {
  input: "",
  resolved: false,
};
const input = document.getElementById("myinput");

input.oninput = function(e) {
  if (!state.resolved) {
    this.value = "";
    state.input += e.data || "";
  }
}

setTimeout(() => {
  state.resolved = true;
  input.value = "Hello " + state.input;
}, 5000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput"/>
```

This is an example to illustrate your case exactely like you decribed it, but in my opinion blocking the typing in the field is not a good behavior for a user. Maybe a better solution would be to clearly disable the input until promise resolves, or to prepend the value to the current typing state when in comes like is has been suggested in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I need to:

1. capture the onkeydown event of the input.
2. On the event:

- call the preventDefault to stop its default behavior;
- add the event on a list;

3. After the promise terminates, o need to  go to that list and manually simulate the keystrokes...

This is far from the ideal, but already do something similar to control our dropdowns more effectively...

I really hoped that some more elegant solution could be found...

Comment: do you realise that by doing this, the whole input will be essentially look like it is "hanged"? It is worse than disabling it

Comment: You seem to know exactely what you want to do so what is causing you a problem ? What part of your implementation is blocking you ? You didn't show any of your code...

Comment: @Peterrabbit Well, this is a very ugly way of solving this... and I didn't write the code yet... When I write the post, I was hoping that would exists some clean and elegant way of solving this...

Comment: Of solving what ? You are describing a desired behavior that is wrong by essence but any other solution like disable the field etc seems to not be acceptable so maybe there is some x y problem here or something. What is your initial problem ? What do you really need to solve ?